# Sharing projects between IntelliJ and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I am about to start work on an existing Java project with other programmers, and they are Eclipse users. I am using IntelliJ (rather fond of its editor...) and would like to know whether I can continue to use it on this project or whether I have to switch to Eclipse. Note that they (as I) use Git for source control, and they are using Maven (which, frankly, I have no experience in, though I know that IntelliJ supports it).

Any thoughts?

Comment: If the project is setup properly you should have no problem importing their code into intellij. And intellij 12 has built in git support, that's pretty good so no problem there either.

Answer (score 1):

If it counts for anything, we're found that there was no problem getting the two environments to work together. We cloned the projects into a set of folders independent of IntelliJ. I then created an empty project in IntelliJ and attached the Maven pom files to that project. Voila - everything talks to each other and interactions with the Git repository work properly.

Comment: Is it possible without Maven pom?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that could work, but there is an option under `Project Settings | Modules`
where you could set the `Dependency Storage Format` to .classpath files.

At least it could be a start and maybe it helps.